# Limit mysql data value to 100.0

Tags: mysql

I want to put completion of task in percentage (eg. 24.5,88.4,12.9,100.0,etc), the maximum value is 100.0

I have try using decimal(3,1) but it gave me maksimum of 99.9 ,
decimal(4,1) gave me maksimum of 999.9

is there any other correct data type for my problem ?

Comment: How about store it as an INT(4) and divide by 10 when you display

Comment: @Adrian Cornish That's what I was going to suggest but I had a hard time deciphering what he was trying to accomplish.

Comment: INT(4) does not actually limit to 4 digits. Giving a length specifier with INT is, to my knowledge, only useful when using zero padding. You can still insert 12345 into an INT(4) column and have it pulled out as 12345.

Comment: @MiloLaMar sounds like he wants DB constraints in MySQL

Comment: @Corbin In all these years I never tried - you are quite correct - it will not enforce a constraint on the size of the int. Wow - learn something everyday :-)

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for helping out, an INT wont allowed me to safe decimal point 99.7 will be saved as 100

Comment: A percent is a number between 0 and 100 inclusive right?  If you want a tenth of a percent, use a number between 0 and 1000 inclusive.  MySQL doesn't have this as a datatype, but just use SMALLINT (2 bytes of storage) and constrain the values with whatever code is inserting them.

Comment: @MiloLaMar percent can be 2.5 % ,3.5%,7.9 %,etc. Your suggestion using SMALLINT wont work, I will lost my decimal point.

Comment: If you must store it in the database as a decimal, use DECIMAL(4,1) and you'll have to restrict 0.0 <= percent <= 100.0 in your code elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe MySQL still doesn't support check constraints. However, you can use an INSERT/UPDATE trigger that verifies the new value of the column and throws an error if it's outside a range that you specify.

Comment: +1 since triggers appear to be the only safe way to do this (safe in terms of the database enforcing its own constraints). Though I wouldn't necessarily error so much as force the value to be in the correct range. Not all will agree with silent enforcement but that would be okay if documented as the behaviour.

Comment: I like your solution using trigger, I might accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't think MySQL has a native way of doing this.  You are left to do it either with your external application or using a stored procedure.

Comment: I agree with you, just wondering is this possible or not, I want to prevent any data input more than 100.0 using only db data type

Comment: Those are both viable soultions but not necessarily the safest - use of external applications or stored procedure would still allow a client to connect to the DB and put in faulty data. Constraints (or triggers) would prevent this (my mantra is that the DB should ebforce its own constraints rather than rely on the goodness of others).